# Regex match last match before group

Tags: regex, regex-group

I can't make a good regex to find last content between pipe characters `|` before specified match.

I want to find `"           313.175,89-"` (or whatever could be between `|` signs) immediately before  `|401 |`.

`|Posting text         |                Amount|BTC | |                                                   |Beginning balance    |                 0,00 |    | |     2|29.07.2021|29.07.2021| 401 ARD DEP. PLN  OPROC.: 0   OD: 29.07.2021 DO:  |                     |           313.175,89-|401 | |      |          |          | KAPITALU: 612313`

All I have is `\|.*?(?=\|401.\|)` but matching everything from newline sing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is almost there, but the problem is your regex will match from the *first* pipe due to `.*?` also matching pipes.

Replace `\|.*?` with `[^|]*` to match only non-pipes:

```
[^|]*(?=\|401 \|)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/f4AO7EDFC82B9f).

This works by matching any number of characters that are not a pipes  and that are followed by `|401 |`.

Note that the pipe within the character class does *not* have to be escaped, because most characters lose their special meaning when used in a character class and pipe is one of them.

---

To also omit the leading/trailing spaces of your target, use `[^| ]*(?= *\|401 \|)`.

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/zcVwbNtl0a1vyA).

Comment: Hi, I had an error in stack editor formatting and my backslashes disappeared, but still my regex was not correct. It is working with yours - Its very clever to use [^a] in this case! 
Thank you.